# Issue installing Rubygems 2.0.3 (Ruby 2.0.0-p195) - No directory?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

There I was thinking getting setup to build a RoR application would be easy. All I had to do was download Ruby, RubyGems and Rails. It's been 48 hours of headaches (rbenv can't seem to install the current version of Ruby so I had to repeat the process with RVM).

I can't install Rubygems either by running the setup file or through RVM. Here are the results:

```
"unknown:rubygems-2.0.3 aok617$ ruby setup.rb
/Users/aok617/rubygems-2.0.3/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:318:in `read': Is a directory - /Users/aok617/.gemrc (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /Users/aok617/rubygems-2.0.3/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:318:in `load_file'
    from /Users/aok617/rubygems-2.0.3/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /Users/aok617/rubygems-2.0.3/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
    from /Users/aok617/rubygems-2.0.3/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/aok617/rubygems-2.0.3/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from setup.rb:45:in `'
unknown:rubygems-2.0.3 aok617$ "
```

And when I try to use RVM:

```
unknown:rubygems-2.0.3 aok617$ rvm install rubygems 2.0.3
Retrieving rubygems-2.0.3
Extracting rubygems-2.0.3 ...
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-2.0.3 for .
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=:@global GEM_HOME= /Users/aok617/.rvm/rubies//bin/ruby -d /Users/aok617/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.3/setup.rb',
please read /Users/aok617/.rvm/log/1372015627_rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
mkdir: : No such file or directory
mkdir: : No such file or directory
unknown:rubygems-2.0.3 aok617$
```

The install log simply states:

```
[2013-06-23 20:13:14] /Users/aok617/.rvm/rubies//bin/ruby
env: /Users/aok617/.rvm/rubies//bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

The common error seems to be that it is not a directory but I've followed two different sets of instructions. I don't see why the error keeps appearing.

Comment: Why are you installing Rubygems manually? Wasn’t it installed when you installed Ruby (via RVM I suppose)?

Comment: Do you get anything if you enter `ls /Users/aok617/.rvm/gems`?

Comment: Thanks, I have been completely let down by Rbenv. I couldn't tell what was native and what was installed any more so had to restore the entire system. I then repeated the process with RVM and Homebrew and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Rbenv simple would not work installing Ruby 2.0.0. I believe this is because the gem path was not specified properly, however I have not found clear instructions for setting this up correctly. I would recommend uninstalling rbenv completely (system restore if necessary) and then performing a fresh install using RVM and Homebrew. Follow instructions on RVM website.